# WebClient.DownloadString throws a 'System.Net.WebException'

Tags: c#, html, .net, webclient

WebClient.DownloadString fails every time it is run, throwing a 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll. Is there something wrong with how it is being called? Code below.

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Basic {0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["which_api_token"]);
                try
                {
                    var jsonString = wc.DownloadString(string.Format("{0}/subjects/{1}", 
                            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["which_api_url"], 
                            Uri.EscapeDataString(subjectName)));
                    return result;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    result.Status = ResultStatus.Failed;
                    return result;
                }
           }
```

Comment: What's the exception's message? May shed some light on it

Comment: you're not doing anything with the `Exception` you're "catching"...  insert this line of code into your catch block `throw new Exception(ex.Message);` and get rid of that `return result;` this will give you a better understanding of the error (please don't forget to share the error with us, this time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebException give you the error.

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers["Authorization"] = string.Format("Basic {0}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["which_api_token"]);
    try
    {
        var jsonString = wc.DownloadString(string.Format("{0}/subjects/{1}", 
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["which_api_url"], 
                Uri.EscapeDataString(subjectName)));
        return result;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        WebException we = ex as WebException;
        if (we != null && we.Response is HttpWebResponse)
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
            // it can be 404, 500 etc...
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        }
        result.Status = ResultStatus.Failed;
        return result;
    }
}
```